# C# What is my best option? Service/Application/Multiple Applications

Tags: projects-and-solutions, application-design

I am developing a solution that requires a number of tasks to be completed at various times. Example:

- Task 1 - Monitor mailbox, process mail items
- Task 2 - Monitor mailbox (different folder), process mail items
- Task 3 - Generate PDF reports

  Task 4 - Monitor folder, distribute files via email as attachments when new ones arrive.

I have already implemented the solution, however, it was basically just a quick fix to get the thing running. Now that it is up, I want to revisit the current setup and improve it so it is as efficient as possible.

For the current solution I have created a sepearate application for each different task and used the Task Scheduler to execute them at specific times.

- Task 1 is a console application that runs on a scheduled task every 5 minutes
- Task 2 is a console application that runs on a scheduled task every 5 minutes (2 minutes after the first application this is because Task 1 will move emails into the folder Task 2 is monitoring)
- Task 3 is run at 5am every day as a runonce application on a scheduled task
- Task 4 is running indefinetly.

My question is, does this seem like a reasonable approach for a solution to this type of application? Do some of the tasks seem better as a service rather than an application?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are task 1 and task 2 seperate items? Seems to me they could be combined into the same executable and run one directly after the other. This prevents race conditions too where task 1 hasn't finished before task 2 tries to take over and process mail that's in the middle of being moved.

Comment: Task 2 has some heavy processing at times (PDF Generation) so I didn't want this to affect Task 1 as if they run back to back then Task 1 would have to wait on Task 2 to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service sounds like the right way to approach this.

Long running subtasks such as PDF generation are well suited to perform using the asynchronous programming method, i.e. using worker threads that call back to the parent thread upon completion. This way the monitor tasks can run independently of the action tasks.

Comment: Thanks, I was 99% sure it was the correct way, just really needed some clarification incase there was a better way.

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd probably use a single service which can be easily configured to run the various tasks (so that if you want to separate them later, you can do so).

Scheduling specific applications is okay and certainly a simpler way of working, but this *feels* more like a service to me. Of course, if you separate out the "doing stuff" logic from the "invocation" side of things, you can easily switch from one to the other.

The efficiency side of things is unlikely to change much by this decision. Do you have good grounds to be worried about the overall efficiency at the moment? Have you profiled your applications to work out where any bottlenecks are? I'd say they're unlikely to be in the scheduling side of things.

Comment: I agree my initial idea was to create a Service. However, as I don't really have any experience creating services I thought (for quickness) I would create a solution that would be easy enough to get up and running. I think my main concern is the PDF Creation. Task 2 monitors a folder that can contains emails which trigger a report to be generated. This taks roughly 5-10 seconds to process, my concern is when the mailbox begins to get bigger, with more and more report emails coming in it could start to slow down and even start to miss it's 5 minute deadline.

Comment: @James: Well want do you want it to do if it *does* take longer than 5 minutes? At the moment presumably another task will start processing the same folder, which sounds like a bad idea. You could use a computer-wide Mutex to avoid this - it's basically an easy way to see of another process is already running. The idea of prototyping using a scheduled console app and then migrating it to a service later is a fine one IMO.

Comment: Yeah what would happen at the moment is the Tasks will just start again which starts to cause an issue as if a PDF report is generating, the email is still sitting in the inbox (as it hasn't yet been moved) so it will pick up the same email and start processing it again. I suppose to avoid this I could move it to a temporary folder. However, I would prefer if the application was able to determine whether to trigger the task or not. I will have a look into the Mutex stuff thanks.